# Python Mysql connector locking other users

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have a long running python script that connects to a MySQL database using MySQL Connector Python. This process makes an http request and inserts data into a table approx. every 8 minutes. The database connection is and cursor is opened once when the process starts. Lately other users have had extremely long running queries or just locked out from the table. This was not an issue before introducing this script. The table that they are being locked out of is being used in a select statement at the start of the script but never in the insert or update statements that take place every 8 minutes going forward.

Should I be closing the cursor during the sleep periods? or even the database connection as well?

EDIT:
At the start of the script a set of data is selected. This the master list of items that will need to be processed, approx. 2000 rows.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # DATABASE CONNECTION
    db_args = {
        'host': '',
        'user': '',
        'passwd': '',
        'database': ''
        }

    dbconn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_args)
    cursor = dbconn.cursor()

    # get the data
    cursor.execute("select * from tbl as a join tbl2 as b")
    products = cursor.fetchall()
    for product in products:
        main(product, cursor)
        time.sleep(440)
```

main is making an http request, getting JSON data and then using the cursor to a make couple insert and/or update statements. With the size of product list and the sleep time, the process takes almost 10 days so the process remains running in background.

Comment: There isn't enough information to say definitively what "the best" answer would be, but cursors are generally a "last resort" when working with databases primarily because they are inefficient. Can you add more detail to the question to describe what it is this cursor does during the data import? Is just an ETL process?

Comment: yes, updating question

Comment: For a interval of this magnitude I would probably reconnect every time, unless there is some value in keeping it open constantly.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything for table A and table B to join on, so will assume this is pseudocode. Databases are good for many things, but this would likely be more efficient as a separate application or utility that reads the data from the external sources, batches it up, then inserts the data in chunks of 5000 records or more depending on whether it's an insert or update. If this is affecting business operations, there could be justification for the development time.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, that is what I have went ahead and implemented. That is easy enough to implement. I still would like to know if this is a known issue or if anyone has any information on why that would happen. I have not found anything in the documentation or stack overflow on the issue.

Comment: @Matigo, Yes, the SQL statement I am actually using works fine. The data from the requests is being stored as raw JSON in text file as well as putting the important stuff in database. I think I will just close the connection between requests to fix the problem.